# How to create rules for work item in azure devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, azure-dashboard

I want to make a rule for a work item, for instance, that the **target end date** shouldn't come before the **target start date**.

Reference screenshot:

[image]

Is there something like an extension I can use to create rules; could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Azure DevOps does not support date validation, and no related extension was found to achieve the requirement.

You can see all the supported rules from [Apply rules to workflow states (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/apply-rules-to-workflow-states?view=azure-devops).

Besides, field rules don't support assigning values that are the sum of two other fields or performing other- mathematical calculations. However, you may find a solution that fits your needs via the [TFS Aggregator (Web Service)](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tfsaggregatorteam.tfs-aggregator-web-service) Marketplace extension. See [Custom rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-reference?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance#custom-rules).

The possible approach I can think of is to create your own custom control (for web access and VS). Examples for custom controls you may find here:
[WitCustomControls](https://github.com/yingang/WitCustomControls)